# TSLint: Unused var keyword

Tags: typescript, tslint

I've configured TSLint for my TypeScript project and I don't know what does the warning `forbidden var keyword` mean. Here is a minimal example, which results in the TSLint warning:

```
var x: number = 1;
```

Thank you.

**Edit:** I'm using the [sample tslint.json](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/docs/sample.tslint.json).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means you are not allowed to declare using var syntax

```
var = 1;
```

It's an Ecmascript 6 rule, it's purpose would be to ensure you don't accidentally re-declare the same variable twice in the same scope, giving it another meaning unintentionally.

See this page: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var

Comment: Just to make it more obvious, you can instead use `let x...` or `const x..` instead of `var x...`